# Easiest way to setup Ubuntu as a VPN server (L2TP) for a home router to connect

Tags: server, vpn, amazon-ec2, l2tp

I'm trying to create/deploy a VPN to solve a connection issue regarding a game I'm playing (Xbox). For this, I'm setting up a VPN on a EC2 machine on AWS and I want to connect from a home router. I have tried VPN services (ExpressVPN) but they offer 2 alternatives.

- OpenVPN -> I cannot connect from my router (TP-LINK AC 1750).
- L2TP/ipsec -> Works, but does not offer support on the required region (Brazil, Sao Paulo).

My router allows PPTP and L2TP without shared secret.

I haven't found any information on how to setup a L2TP server on Ubuntu Server **without a shared secret**. For now, I have deployed a PPTP VPN that I can connect to, but I need the L2TP solution.

**Do you have any information, link, tutorial or anything on How to Setup a L2TP VPN without a Shared Key (only user & pass) with Ubuntu Server?** (Ideally 20.04)

PS: My interest is not on security, but rather "being" on the Brazil region.

PS 2: The most similar that I have found are this, but I cannot adapt them to use without Shared Secret (they are PKI) -> https://bluegrid.io/setting-up-a-vpn-server-with-strongswan-on-ubuntu-20-04/

Best regards, thanks!

Comment: Connecting your router to a VPN would not have anything to do with Ubuntu.  Consult with your router's documentation.

Comment: I looking to deploy a L2TP VPN without a shared secret on Ubuntu Server, for that I have not found any information. That's the question, the rest is context.